# how to search in <tr> table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i search using the table below as well as lower and uppercase search filters any help on JavaScript will be appreciated thank you :)

```
<div class="title">

<h3>Products</h3>

</div>
<table class="list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="left">List A</th>
            <th class="right">List B</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-hover">
        <tr>
            <td class="left">apple</td>
            <td class="rightt">100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">snapple</td>
            <td class="right">200</td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/w3f9gx5c/

```js
var $rows = $('.list tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

  $rows.show().filter(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
    return !~text.indexOf(val);
  }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search" />
<table class="list">
  <tbody class="table-hover">
    <tr>
      <td class="left">apple</td>
      <td class="rightt">100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">snapple</td>
      <td class="right">200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">SNAPPLE</td>
      <td class="right">200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">APPLE</td>
      <td class="right">200</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Explain downvote plz!

Comment: @mia is what you are looking?

Comment: can i say i love u hehehhe thank you soo muchhh :))))))))) u made my day thanks a lott it workss like charmmm

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr td:contains("text to search for")') //returns all td tags that have the text you enter
```

[Case insensitive :contains](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/), via Google.

Comment: can you give me the full code for search please it will be really helpful thanks

Comment: that is literally it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e0unsvz3/ am i doing something wrong then?

Comment: that returns the objects you want, but you have to do something with them if you expect anything to happen. http://jsfiddle.net/p7hgyxmq/